# how to extract a number in between strings using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following text

Stat indicator : 01245 Values loaded

Some irrelevant data

Stat indicator : 13452 Values loaded

My output should be giving me numbers 01245, 13452

Heres what I have tried

```
with open('test.txt') as fd:
    data = fd.read()
val_to_pattern = {'stat': r'Stat indicator : .{5}\n'}
val_dict = {}
for key, patt in val_to_pattern.items():
    val_dict[key] = re.findall(patt, data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
val_to_pattern = {'stat': r'Stat indicator\s*:\s*(\d+)'}
```

Note that `\s*:\s*` pattern matches a `:` optionally wrapped with 0+ whitespaces and the `(\d+)` part matches and *captures* into Group 1 any 0+ digits (note that `re.findall` only returns *captured* substrings if capturing groups are set in the regex).

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2S79Tf/1) (the green text will be the result).

Alternatively, if the number of digits in the indicator stats is always 5 use either of

```
 val_to_pattern = {'stat': r'Stat indicator\s*:\s*(\d{5})\b'}
 val_to_pattern = {'stat': r'Stat indicator\s*:\s*(\d{5})(?!\d)'}
```

`\b` is word boundary that will require a non-word char or end of string after 5 digits and the `(?!\d)` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 0):

You can used regex `\d`, and if you know the size of your number you can use `{size}` with it.

> \d{3} Returns a match where the string contains 3 digits (numbers from
>   0-9)
>
> \d{3,5} Returns a match where the string contains 3 to 5 digits
>   (numbers from 0-9)

So you can used `r'\d{3,5}'` as regex pattern

```
import re

with open('test.txt') as fd:
    data = fd.read()
val_to_pattern = {'stat': r'\d{5}'}
val_dict = {}
for key, patt in val_to_pattern.items():
    re_find = re.findall(patt, data)
    val_dict[key] = re.findall(patt, data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex, you could implement a straightforward loop.

```
  1 with open('test.txt') as fd:
  2     data = fd.read()
  3
  4 nums = []
  5 temp = ""
  6 is_dig = False
  7 for char in data:
  8      if char.isdigit():
  9           temp += char
 10           is_dig = True
 11      elif is_dig:
 12           nums.append(temp)
 13           temp = ""
 14           is_dig = False
 15 print(nums)
```